# Writing to a table on a read only slave

Tags: mysql, proxysql

I've a MySQL master-slave replication setup where the slave is marked as read-only=ON. I've some stored procedures that I want to route through ProxySQL to the slave and prefer not to run on the master. Each stored procedure logs into an exception-logging table using an exception-logging stored procedure if any exception arises. I can set the definer for this as root or some other user with SUPER privilege. But that would break replication when the same set of primary key auto increment values would sync from the master for this exception table.

Would using replicate-ignore-table make sense? How safe is that with ROW based replication? Please suggest if there's any better way of doing this.